# Create variable in kustomize manifest

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize, argocd, gitops

I have what I would consider a common use case but I am really struggling to find a solution:

I want to reuse a variable in `Kustomize` patches in our deployments.   Specifically, we are using commit IDs to reference image tags (Use Case A) and k8s Jobs related to the deployments (Use Case B).

We use a setup where for each ArgoCD app we have a `/base/` folder and `/overlays/[environment-name]`, this base is patched with a `kustomization.yaml`.

#### Use Case A:

A very straightforward usage - in `/overlays/[environment-name]` we have a `kustomization.yaml` which uses:

```
images:
- name: our-aws-repo-url
  newName: our-aws-repo-url
  newTag: commit-id
```

Works like a charm since we can re-use this both for the Deployment itself as well as its related Jobs all with one commit reference.

#### Use Case B:

The problem:

We use N Jobs to e.g. do migrations for 0 downtime deployments where we run alembic containers that run the migration and we have a `waitforit` `initContainer` that listens for the Job to get completed i.e. when the migration was successful in order to deploy.

The problem is now that I need to touch 4 files in one service's overlay to patch the id everywhere (which we use to recognize the Job):

- deployment.yaml like so:

```
- image: groundnuty/k8s-wait-for:v1.4
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  args: 
   - "job"
   - "job-commit-id"
```

- job.yaml itself to change re-trigger of Job for new deployment/potential migration:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-commit-id
```

- kustomization.yaml as described in Use Case A.

What I think should be possible instead is to:

1. define variable `commit-id` somehow in kustomization.yaml and
2. for Use Case A & B do something like:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-${commit-id}
```

```
- image: groundnuty/k8s-wait-for:v1.4
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  args: 
   - "job"
   - "job-${commit-id}"
```

```
images:
- name: our-aws-repo-url
  newName: our-aws-repo-url
  newTag: ${commit-id}
```

Goal: when developers do PRs for releases, they should only touch one reference to the commit ID to prevent typos etc. (also easier to review instead of checking commit ID in N places)

Caveat: I am sure there is also another way to do migrations instead of Jobs but this is generally a common thing: how to re-use a variable inside kustomize.

I know I can reference ENV variable in kustomize but I want to reuse a variable within the manifests.

Comment: Why not using helm chart with values? this way you  "patch" (upgrade) the helm with your new values and you use the desired variables as values

Comment: I am asking a question for kustomize specifically because that is what we opted for. I am aware that Helm can do this but I'd rather ask about this first instead of refactoring all of our deployments for this reason alone. Helm has a lot of other complexity I really don't need.

Comment: You can use Kustomization edit to update your Kustomization resources as well, which can lead out that you will have a script for the updates

Comment: @CodeWizard can you be more specific? do you mean a CLI command? keep in mind that we are using ArgoCD which actually deploys the manifests

Comment: I know you are using ArgoCD, read about it here: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/parameters/, you should use `.argocd-source.yaml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I want to reuse a variable within the manifests.

This is not how you typically work with Kustomize. Its a good thing that things are *declarative* and *explicit* when working with Kustomize.

> when developers do PRs for releases, they should only touch one reference to the commit ID to prevent typos etc. (also easier to review instead of checking commit ID in N places)

yes and no.

That there is a change in four places should not be seen as a problem, in my opinion. That there is *human toil* to update four places **is the problem**.

The solution to human toil is typically **automation**. By using [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) in an automated pipeline (e.g. Jenkins - or a shellscript) can you automate your manifest-update to take a single parameter - this can optionally be automated directly for each build after you have a git "commit id" available. The pipeline need to run four `yq`-commands to update the four Yaml fields. See e.g. [assign operation](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/assign-update) and [github action - pipeline example](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/github-action). No other variables are needed.

Comment: I like the approach and I like the idea behind `yq` - just need to find a way for my service repo to checkout the manifest repo and update the field & make PR but I guess that's a separate issue :) I'll see if I can stich it together

Comment: Update: we solved the issue as you suggested! Took us a minute but we have been using it now for a week and we have already saved quite a lot of time so big thanks! We also decided to package it in a GH workflow (GH Action soon) so people with a similar setup can benefit from the approach as well. https://github.com/kranushealth/gitops-release-pr